# Print underscore separated integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

Since python3.6, you can use underscore to separate digits of an integer.
For example

```
x = 1_000_000
print(x)  #1000000
```

This feature was added to easily read numbers with many digits and I found it very useful. But when you print the number you always get a number not separated with digits. Is there a way to print the number with its digits separated with underscore.

P.S. I want the output as integer not as string. Not `"1_000_000"` but `1_000_000`

Comment: I'm not sure your question makes sense.  The underscore integer format is for defining literals within your Python script.  How you _view_ an integer when printed is another story...but you may not be in control of that.  Note that the answers below are in fact printing a string, which you said you didn't want.

Comment: `x = 1_000_000;y='{:_}.format(x);print(isinstance(y,str)` will print `True`. Below answer didnot return a `int`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks for the info. I said "not string" just to discourage answers like ```cast the int to str and then loop through the str to separed each third character digit by underscore```.

Comment: Well that's one way of doing it `:-)`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try using this:

```
>>> x = 1_000_000
>>> print(f"{x:_}")
1_000_000
```

[Here are details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)

Another way would be to use `format` explicitly:

```
>>> x = 1_000_000
>>> print(format(x, '_d'))
1_000_000
```

Comment: In python 3, for f-strings it's `number = 100000; f"{number:_}"`.

Answer (score 7):

```
print('{:_}'.format(x))
```

Output:

```
1_000_000
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, we could also handle this requirement using regex:

```
x = 1_000_000
out = re.sub(r'(\d{3})', '\\1,', str(x)[::-1])[::-1]
print(out)
```

This prints:

```
1,000,000
```

The idea here is to reverse the integer string, and then to replace, from left to right (in the original string), each collection of 3 digits with the same digits plus a comma separator.

Comment: Although then you do run into the whole "no one agrees on what the separator should be" because `1,000,000` is the number one, with an illegal second comma in Europe. At that point, use an actual locale-aware number formatter package.

Comment: Horrible format. Never use `','` or `'.'` as a digit separator.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Depends on where in Europe.