# How to format long digits in Python -- to group every 3 digits?

Tags: python, decimal

I want to format long numbers in Python in a way in which every 3 digits from the end get grouped:

```
10000000    --> 10 000 000
40186356.92 --> 40 186 356.92
```

Is there a built-in way to do it in Python? Or will I have to do it manually?

---

The numbers are decimals, and I use the library `decimal` too.

Comment: At the very least, use the format that would still works as a number in Python, with underscores instead of spaces? And then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60370869/print-underscore-separated-integer will do that automatically for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [37]: format(10000000, ',').replace(',', ' ')
Out[37]: '10 000 000'

In [38]: format(40186356.92, ',').replace(',', ' ')
Out[38]: '40 186 356.92'
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with a `decimal` number too?

Comment: I see that it'll work with `decimal`

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work on numbers greater than 1e16.

Comment: But rather than spaces, you almost certainly want to use a character that python can just put in for you (e.g. `print(f"{1234567:_}")` or `print(f"{1234567:,}")`)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans why do you say "almost certantly" rather than "certantly"? What is it what'll make the exceptions?

Comment: You never said _why_ you needed this, so the only person who knows for sure is you. Everyone else can, at best, be almost certain.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans if I am the only person who knows, how could you have said "you almost certantly **want to**"? Haven't you contradicted yourself by pretending to know what I **want to**?

Comment: Not sure if you're trying to pick a fight or understand the phrasing I used, but again: because your post doens't explain the "why", folks are left to guess, and my guess is that if you care about the code being pythonic even in the slightest (and I further guess that you do) then you would want something that Python can already do. And that that's something you didn't know about, and so couldn't have thought of, but now that you know, you would probably want to use this. With all those guesses based on personal experience, having worked with and mentored many programmers for decades.